# Java: difference between initializing an array of integers using brackets and using new keyword

Tags: java, arrays

When initializing an array of integers using brackets, does it create an object on the heap?

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] values = {1,2,3};  //1

        int[] list = new int[3];  //2
        list[0] = 1;
        list[1] = 2;
        list[2] = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: short answer yes! values are local stack variable but object allocated in heap.

Comment: @Kishor: what?  They're syntactic sugar for each other, save for the length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, an array is an **object**, so it gets **space** allocated on the **heap**.

Every array type, including primitives, has a class. So when you create an array of primitive `int`, the JVM creates an instance of `int[].class` on the heap.

Comment: So there is no difference between code marked `//1` and code marked `//2`?

Comment: @blafasel there is a rather obvious difference: 2nd one is size 10, first one is size 3